# Notificaciones firebase con app cerrada

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, android-notifications, notificaciones

Estoy implementando un sistema en el que recibo notificaciones push con Firebase.

Si la aplicación está abierta o en segundo plano, soy capaz de capturar la notificación que me envía firebase, cojo los datos y si me interesa muestro una notificación o no, hago lo que necesito.

Para esto, tengo las siguientes clases:

MyFirebaseMessagingService:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

  private static final String LOGTAG = "android-fcm";

  @Override
  public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    if(remoteMessage.getNotification() != null)
    {
        String titulo = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String texto = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

        Log.d(LOGTAG, "NOTIFICACIÓN RECIBIDA");
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "Título: " + titulo);
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "texto: " + texto);

        showNotification(titulo, texto);
    }

    if(remoteMessage.getData() != null)
    {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "DATOS RECIBIDOS");
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "Usuario: " + remoteMessage.getData().get("usuario"));
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "Estado: " + remoteMessage.getData().get("estado"));

        showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("usuario") + " titulo", remoteMessage.getData().get("estado") + " mensaje");
    }
  }

  private void showNotification(String titulo, String texto)
  {
    try {
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background).setContentTitle(titulo).setContentText(texto);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        String t = e.getMessage();
        t = t + "";
    }
  }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private static final String LOGTAG = "android-fcm";
  Button btnToken;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("android");

    if(getIntent().getExtras() != null)
    {
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "DATOS RECIBIDOS (INTENT)");
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "Usuario: " + getIntent().getExtras().getString("usuario"));
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "Estado: " + getIntent().getExtras().getString("estado"));
    }

    btnToken = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnToken);
    btnToken.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Token actualizado: " + refreshedToken, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Log.e("Token", "Token actualizado: " + refreshedToken);
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Como he dicho, con este código, si tengo la app abierta o en segundo plano, al recibir una notificación, la capturo, pasa por el método onMessageReceived y genero localmente la notificación.

Mi problema es el siguiente. Si tengo la app cerrada (la quito de segundo plano), al recibir una notificación de firebase, no pasa por el método onMessageReceived y se me genera automáticamente una notificación la cual yo no puedo capturarla.

¿Hay alguna posibilidad de capturar el mensaje que envía firebase teniendo la app cerrada para, si nos interesa generar la notificación y si no nos interesa no?

No se si hay que capturarla desde otro método o hay que hacer algo diferente.

Comment: Echale un vistazo a esta respuesta (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383238/firebase-notifications-when-app-is-closed) en la versión inglesa de SO.

Comment: Lo miro, muchas gracias

Comment: @David_helo, gracias al link que me has puesto he podido solucionarlo. Si quirees haxz una respuesta y te la publico como válida.

Comment: En el siguiente [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383238/firebase-notifications-when-app-is-closed) tienes tu misma respuesta formulada en SO en inglés, en la cuál le dan una solución válida. Si no, puedes echarle un vistazo a [las guías](https://firebase.google.com/docs/guides/) que presenta [FireBase](https://firebase.google.com/) para intentar solucionar el problema: 1. Como [manejar](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) los mensajes recibidos.
2. Que [tipos de mensajes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_

Comment: Hombre, cúrrate un pelín más la respuesta. Mira [answer] para hacer una buena respuesta

Comment: A ver que tal ahora :P

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81984/discussion-between-pablo-simon-diestefano-and-david-helo).